# “Senior” and “Junior” suffixes on ID cards and passports

Tags: usage, names

And are the suffixes "junior" and "senior" added in the names on passports? And also on identity cards? Or is it just informal and only said aloud?

Comment: Passports for what country? I'm not sure this is an English question. It seems like more of a [travel.se] question.

Comment: Like if Jack Watson Junior is American or English and if he has a passport. It's absolutely not about travelling because I just want to know what name is written on the passport : if the "Junior" is added, or if it's just said informally.

Comment: But it being written on the passport *isn't* an English language issue.

Comment: @Catija - The question is asking about all ID cards, not just passports, so I suppose it could be considered a legitimate "western English-speaking culture" question.

Answer (score 3):

The rule for passports is a political and administrative rule, not a matter of English usage.  It is found in [Home Office documentation of rules for names on passports](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/548220/Annex_A_passports_August_2016.pdf)

> 12 **The prefix/suffix (Jr)**
> 12.1 If an applicant wishes to have Junior on their passport, this should be shown on the
> surname field, provided this is shown on the birth certificate. Birth certificates would normally
> display Junior after the surname.

Subject to the general guidance:

> 1.1 The name by which a person wishes to be known is a matter for the individual. Where
> possible, we should respect their choice whilst recognising that the passport is a document
> issued on behalf of the Crown and must maintain an acceptable standard.

In other words, if you *want* to have "Jr" in your name (and it is on your birth certificate), you can (but you don't have to)

Answer (score 0):

"Senior", "Junior", and similar identifiers are formal parts of a person's name in any English-speaking country.

Most English-speaking countries don't *have* identity cards.  As for the passport, that would be at the discretion of that country's passport agency, but my guess would be typically yes.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this?  My impression is that Jr. or Sr. are distinctly *not* part of the name - i.e. Jack Smith Junior is the second person named "Jack Smith", but his last name is not "Junior"!

Comment: @stangdon - I suppose it's possible for Jack Smith, Jr.'s parents to make the "Junior" part of his last name (by putting `Jack Smith, Jr.` on the birth certificate). "Senior", however, would be a different story!

Comment: @stangdon -- Many official forms have the _suffix_, as it is called, as part of the requested information. In the US, at least, there is no legal definition of what constitutes a name; the US government has no central naming authority.

Comment: "Sr." and "Jr." are almost unknown in the UK, so I have no idea whether or not they are "formal parts of a person's name">

Comment: @Malvolio - Agreed, but then maybe the wording "formal parts of a person's name" is not quite correct.  I've also seen it on forms and such, but I don't think it goes on drivers' licenses, passports, etc.

Comment: I don't recall the forms themselves, but my son's passport and social security card do both read MATHEW JR. I'm pretty certain they go based on what the birth certificate says. With that said, this question isn't quite a fit for here.